# Display Local Time in Apache Airflow UI

Tags: ubuntu, timezone, airflow

How can we configure the Airflow webpage header to display the current time in the local timezone? As shown in the image below, it is currently displaying the UTC time.

[image]

`core.default_timezone` has already been set to `America/New_York`.

[image]

Clicking on the displayed time in the header causes a strange modal to appear:

[image]

The [airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/timezone.html) show a different behavior on clicking it:

[image]

I am running Airflow 1.10.9 on Ubuntu 18.04. Firefox 76.0 is used as the browser. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature shown in Airflow docs is only available from Airflow >= 1.10.10 and is only available for the RBAC UI.

Details: https://airflow.apache.org/blog/airflow-1.10.10/#allow-user-to-chose-timezone-to-use-in-the-rbac-ui